# R create dataframe with row names

Tags: r, datetime

How to create a dataframe with row are dates that are easy to process further? I need to combine several vectors of unequal length together to create this matrix. Also, I don't want the variable name `ch_2013` to be there.

```
library(readr)
library(qpcR)
crsp <- read_csv("~/Documents/crsp.csv")
ch_2015 <- c("2015-03-19",14593,66093)
ch_2013 <- c("2013-09-26",57665,92611,86868,59408,24643,27828)
df = qpcR:::rbind.na(ch_2015,ch_2013)
```

This output

```
        [,1]         [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]    [,7]   
ch_2015 "2015-03-19" "14593" "66093" NA      NA      NA      NA     
ch_2013 "2013-09-26" "57665" "92611" "86868" "59408" "24643" "27828"
```

Answer (score 1):

to set rownames. (consider that row names needs to be unique, otherwise it will be adjusted to be so)

```
rownames(df) <- df[,1]
```

to remove dates from matrix

```
df <- df[,-1]
```